# Noisy or malfunctioning PIR HC-SR505 sensor

Tags: sensor, pir

I bought 5 [PIR Sensors](https://www.ebay.com/itm/HC-SR505-Mini-Infrared-PIR-Motion-Sensor-Precise-Infrared-Detector-Module/201414945373) to trigger when movement is detected, using an Arduino.

During bench tests, all 5 sensors show many false triggers. I wonder if all 5 sensors have something wrong, or whether there is a way to reduce "noise" on the sensor?

1) code is simple - just print out to serial monitor its `digitalRead` values.

2) to reduce IR in the room, the window was closed.

3) wiring scheme is very simple, [example](https://www.mschoeffler.de/2017/08/30/tutorial-how-to-use-the-hc-sr505-pir-sensor-with-the-arduino/)

Still, detection was notified erratically even when I was not in the room.

Any explanations why? And how to overcome this behaviour?

Comment: do you use hysteresis on the MCU input wire?

Comment: @analogsystemsrf - can you please explain more. my scheme is as shown in example linked to the question

Comment: I would first try to locate the problem, instead of the Arduino, just connect an LED to a PIR sensor and power that from a battery. Do you still get false triggers? Then the sensor is too sensitive. If triggering is OK now then we know it is not the sensor. Now instead of the battery, use 5 V from the Arduino. Leave the LED as is and **only** connect 5 V and GND from Arduino to sensor+LED. This will test of the Arduino's supply is OK. See how step-by-step I try to locate the issue.

Comment: You can also try to reduce false triggering by making sure the sensor's output is high for some time like 1 second. So do the digitalRead, when a 1 is read, wait for 1 second and read again, still high? => Only then it's a real trigger.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie - Sensor sets a `HIGH` upon detection for 8 seconds with +/-30% ... so for that amount of time, I think it won't be a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I place a 1kohm resistor at the sr505 negative end which is connected to ground.  Its solve the false positive problem.